# How do I access elements within my array using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have recently created an array using `.map` in jQuery and now I need to access elements within it.  To handle this I simply iterated over the array and tried to grab the various items but I can't seem to get it to work.

```js
$('#go').on('click', function () {
  var arr = $('.plotrow').map(function () {
    var o = {};
    o[this.id] = [
      { lat: $(this).find('.lat input').val() },
      { long: $(this).find('.long input').val() }
    ]
    return o;
  }).get();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="coords">
    <div id="plot1" class="plotrow">
        <h3>Plot 1</h3>
        <div class="lat">
            <input type="text" id="plot1_lat" value="59.545205" class="k-textbox" />
        </div>
        <div class="long">
            <input type="text" id="plot1_long" value="1.53572" class="k-textbox" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="plot2" class="plotrow">
        <h3>Plot 2</h3>
        <div class="lat">
            <input type="text" id="plot2_lat" value="59.21344" class="k-textbox" />
        </div>
        <div class="long">
            <input type="text" id="plot2_long" value="1.33437" class="k-textbox" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="plot output">
        <h3>Output</h3>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="go">Go!</button>
</div>
```

What I want to do it output the `id` the `lat` and the `long` from my array.  No matter what I try I seem to get an `undefined` error.  For example, I wrote the following code:

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(arr[i]['plot1'][0]['lat']);            
}
```

This code returned the `lat` for me but also an error of:

`TypeError: arr[i].plot1 is undefined[Learn More]`

I've tried a couple of variations but nothing seems to work.  Can anyone offer a good way to access my elements?

Comment: I think you want something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ohezw3jr/ (look at developer console)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're iterating over an array that looks like

```
[
    {
        "plot1": [
            {
                "lat": "59.545205"
            },
            {
                "long": "1.53572"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "plot2": [
            {
                "lat": "59.21344"
            },
            {
                "long": "1.33437"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

meaning in the first iteration, you get

```
{"plot1": [ ... ]},
```

but the second iteration gets you

```
{"plot2": [ ... ]},
```

and then your `arr[i]['plot1']` is undefined, as the key is `plot2` etc.

---

It would make it easier on you if you created an object instead

```
$('#go').on('click', function () {
    var obj = {};

  $('.plotrow').each(function() {
    obj[this.id] = {
      lat: $(this).find('.lat input').val(),
      lon: $(this).find('.long input').val()
    };
  });
});
```

and you'd end up with

```
{
    "plot1": {
        "lat": "59.545205",
        "lon": "1.53572"
    },
    "plot2": {
        "lat": "59.21344",
        "lon": "1.33437"
    }
}
```

where you could just do `obj.plot1.lat` to access it, or to iterate do

```
$.each(obj, function(_,item) {
    var lat = item.lat;
    var lon = item.lon;
})
```

Comment: This makes more sense @adeneo I have implemtned this approach which helps to simplify the structure.  One question regarding iteration, `item.lat` and `item.lon` return as undefined.  `item` returns as the row id.

Comment: @Yanayaya - you're right, I forgot that `jQuery.fn.each` has the item as the first argument, but when using just `jQuery.each` the item would be the second argument. They are a bit different. I've edited the answer to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

By changing your for loop to look like this, you can get all of the values you need.

Essentially you were trying to loop over plot1 while you were in plot2.

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var plot = 'plot' + (i + 1);
    console.log(arr[i][plot][0]['lat']);            
    console.log(arr[i][plot][1]['long']);            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Within you [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) would be better to return an object like this:

```
{
  id: this.id,
  lat: $(this).find('.lat input').val(),
  long: $(this).find('.long input').val()
}
```

Code:

```js
$('#go').on('click', function () {
  var arr = $('.plotrow')
    .map(function () {
      return {
        id: this.id,
        lat: $(this).find('.lat input').val(),
        long: $(this).find('.long input').val()
      };
    })
    .get();

  // Accessing element in array
  arr.forEach(function (el) {
    console.log('Element id:', el.id);
    console.log('Element lat:', el.lat);
    console.log('Element long:', el.long);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="coords">
    <div id="plot1" class="plotrow">
        <h3>Plot 1</h3>
        <div class="lat">
            <input type="text" id="plot1_lat" value="59.545205" class="k-textbox" />
        </div>
        <div class="long">
            <input type="text" id="plot1_long" value="1.53572" class="k-textbox" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="plot2" class="plotrow">
        <h3>Plot 2</h3>
        <div class="lat">
            <input type="text" id="plot2_lat" value="59.21344" class="k-textbox" />
        </div>
        <div class="long">
            <input type="text" id="plot2_long" value="1.33437" class="k-textbox" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="plot output">
        <h3>Output</h3>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="go">Go!</button>
</div>
```